# How do I achieve the effect that two div with the width of 50% open simultaneously?

Tags: css, css-animations

I try to create the effect that two gates open simultaneously, I tried modifying the width property but I achieved the desired effect only on the left gate. The idea is that the right gate be closed from the center to the right border. Thanks in advance for your suggestions

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
  }

  .gate {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .left-gate {
    animation-name: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .right-gate {
    animation-name: right;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
  }

  @keyframes left {
    from {
      width: 50%;
    }

    to {
      width: 0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes right {
    from {
      width: 50%;
    }

    to {
      width: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="gate left-gate"></div>
<div class="gate right-gate"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `right: 0` to the right gate:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: goldenrod;
  }

  .gate {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .left-gate {
    animation-name: left;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .right-gate {
    animation-name: right;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  @keyframes left {
    from {
      width: 50%;
    }

    to {
      width: 0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes right {
    from {
      width: 50%;
    }

    to {
      width: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="gate left-gate"></div>
<div class="gate right-gate"></div>
```